# Changing the "Timeout" Variable in agentd.conf

Tags: zabbix

I am currently getting a "Zabbix agent %hostname is unreachable for X minutes". I want to increase this X to another value.

I have done some research and have noticed that I do not have to change the triggers but rather a variable in the .conf file. However, I am unable to actually find this file. I am wondering if this file is independent to each machine and has to be changed on each one (based on preference) or if there is some unique location I must look.

Sorry for the silly question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That actually is a threshold in the trigger expression, not in any configuration files. Go to the host in question, look for triggers. If you want to change this for all hosts, change it in the template. If you want to change this only for a single host, modify the trigger in the template to use [usermacro](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/macros/usermacros) for the threshold, then override that value on the host.